# How do you reset an iPhone 4s without a passcode or iTunes

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4s running iOS 9.3.5 that i would like to wipe and reset. I do not have the passcode. I also do not have access to iTunes. My only computer is a Linux Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried to run iTunes under Wine and PlayOnLinux as suggested in some other posts, but neither of those worked. iTunes wouldn't run under Wine and PlayOnLinux didn't have USB support. 
Installing Windows to a new partition and running iTunes from there is an absolute last resort that i would like to avoid. I am also not reasonably close to an Apple Store.
Is it possible for me to reset this phone without doing that, and if so, how would I do it?

Comment: You may be able to log in through icloud.com, and remote-wipe the phone? Still think you may need your passcode after that, or maybe only your iCloud password. Worth a shot, I think!

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work for me. I can't sign into the 4s with my AppleID because it sends the verification code to my 7+. The reason I am wanting to use the 4s is because I accidentally destroyed the screen on my 7+ and it's now unusable. I was hoping the 4s would get me by for a week or so until I can get an 8 when they drop in about a week. :)

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans Thanks. I was able to set a trusted phone number in iCloud through the web interface. After that I turned on Find My iPhone on the 4s using the trusted number to verify. Then I was able to use Find My iPhone to wipe the 4s. If you want to make it an official answer it might help some other people.

Comment: Made the answer! I'm happy it worked! Have fun with your 4s, was my daily driver for ~5 years. A bit slow nowadays but certainly capable still!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wipe your phone remotely by using the web-based [iCloud Dashboard](http://icloud.com), using the Find My iPhone feature. You can add a trusted phone number through the same interface, and use that phone number to receive the code to wipe your phone.